# Update table with key-value pair array as data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to create a table with a key value array passed as the data. I want it to be able to update as new data is passed. I am having trouble with appending it (current code) and/or updating it (previous code). Any suggestions?

This is my current code:

```
 let tr = table.selectAll('tr')
                        .data(arr);
        
tr.exit().remove();
                        
tr.enter()
            .append('tr')
            .merge(tr)
            .each(function(d) {
                let td = d3.select(this)
                    .selectAll('td')
                    .data(arr);

                td.exit()
                    .remove();

                td = td.enter()
                    .append('td')
                    .merge(td)
                    .html(d => d.key);
                td = td.enter()
                    .append('td')
                    .merge(td)
                    .html(d => d.value);

            });
            
tr.exit().remove();
```

Previous Iteration - Doesn't update properly but appends each key and corresponding value properly:

```
let tr = table.selectAll('tr')
                        .data(arr);
tr.exit().remove();
                        
tr.enter()
            .append('tr')
            .each(function(d) {
                let td = d3.select(this);
                for (let col in d) {
                    td
                        .append('td')
                        .html(d[col]);
                }
});

tr.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

1. Name your selections, eg: `const trExit = tr.exit().remove();`
2. D3 selections are immutable. Therefore, reassign when merging (if you are referencing that selection later), eg: `tr = trEnter.merge(tr);`
3. Create nested enter-update-exit selections for both `<tr>` and `<td>`, and drop that `each`.

Given your (I assume) data structure, it could be:

```
let tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data, d => d.key);

const trExit = tr.exit().remove();

const trEnter = tr.enter().append("tr");

tr = trEnter.merge(tr);

let td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(d => Object.values(d));

const tdExit = td.exit().remove();

const tdEnter = td.enter().append("td");

td = tdEnter.merge(td);

td.html(d => d);
```

You don't need the exit for the `<td>`, since it seems to me that the table always have 2 columns.

Here is a basic demo:

```js
const dataArray = [{
  key: "foo",
  value: 11
}, {
  key: "bar",
  value: 12
}, {
  key: "baz",
  value: 13
}, {
  key: "foobar",
  value: 14
}, {
  key: "foobaz",
  value: 15
}, {
  key: "barbaz",
  value: 16
}];

const table = d3.select("body").append("table");

d3.interval(() => update(dataArray.slice(-(~~(Math.random() * dataArray.length)))), 1000);

function update(data) {
  let tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data, d => d.key);

  const trExit = tr.exit().remove();

  const trEnter = tr.enter().append("tr");

  tr = trEnter.merge(tr);

  let td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(d => Object.values(d));

  const tdExit = td.exit().remove();

  const tdEnter = td.enter().append("td");

  td = tdEnter.merge(td);

  td.html(d => d);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```